# Maintain reference inside a for-loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, reference

I have the following code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
    var x = functionThatCreatesADivElement();

    someElement.appendChild(x.getDiv());  // this works fine

    nodelist[i].onclick = function() {
       x.someFunction();                  // this always refer to the last 'x' object
    }
}


function functionThatCreatesADivElement() {
   var div = document.createElement("div");

   this.someFunction = function() {}

   this.getDiv = function() {
      return div;
   }

   return this;
}
```

the problem is that the execution of `nodelist[0].onclick` is exactly the same as `nodelist[4].onclick` (assuming  that i = 4 is the last node).

I believe the references of the previously iterated are changing to point to the currently iterated element.

What is the proper way of doing this?

EDIT: Added some more code and changed the name of the function cause it was too confusing

Comment: Is the `functionThatReturnsADivElement()` returning the same value each time?

Comment: each time you call it, it returns `this`, that way I can call functions like `x.hide()` or `x.getDOMElemement()`

Comment: For performance issues, at least, you could put the call outside the for loop, then.  I don't think that would fix your issue of references, though.

Comment: It returns `this`? That means it returns the `window` object unless `functionThatReturnsADivElement()` is a bound function.

Comment: Sorry, the name i chose is confusing. The function return 'this'  and it has an inner function that returns the "div" element.

Comment: Are you actually using `new` to invoke the function? The way it is right now, `this` is still referring to `window`, which means your `someFunction` and `getDiv` are being overwritten on every invocation, and you're returning `window`.

Comment: Ok I solved it. As you said, I wasnt using "new". using new solves it

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. The first problem is that JavaScript variables don't have block scopes.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_Scope):

> When you declare a variable outside of any function, it is called a global variable, because it is available to any other code in the current document. When you declare a variable
> within a function, it is called a local variable, because it is available only within that
> function.
>
> JavaScript does not have block statement scope;

You aren't enclosing a the `x` variable in a function, so all of your onclick callbacks are using the same `x` variable, which point to whatever element is last in the loop since that will be the last one to have overwritten `x`.

Doing this for your loop should work:

```
nodelist.forEach(function (nodeitem) {
    var x = functionThatCreatesADivElement();

    someElement.appendChild(x.getDiv());

    nodeitem.onclick = function() {
        x.someFunction();
    }
});
```

The second problem is that your `functionThatCreatesADivElement()` constructor function is not being called correctly.  Use `new functionThatCreatesADivElement()` since you are invoking a constructor function.

Comment: Your solution would work, except that `x` is still going to have the same value... no longer because of a variable scope issue, but rather because the function is always returning the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to use

```
var x = new functionThatCreatesADivElement();

function functionThatCreatesADivElement() {
   var div = document.createElement("div");

   this.someFunction = function() {}

   this.getDiv = function() {
      return div;
   }

   //return this;  //Using new instead of returning this
```

}